# Como verificar o tamanho de uma div e ajusta-la pelo jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Como posso verificar o tamanho de uma div com jquery?
A altura dessa div e automática, porém gostaria de limitar a sua atura.
Eu estou atribuindo uma classe para este elemento, pois o mesmo se encontra dentro de um loop da minha aplicação de servidor, logo vai se repetir.
A lógica seria da seguinte forma:
Caso seja menor que 200px, gostaria de igualar a 200px.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode pegar a altura da `div` usando `$(seletor).outerHeight(true)`. Este método pega a altura completa do elemento, incluindo `padding` e `border`, se houver.

Em relação a igualar a altura caso seja menor que `200px`, você pode colocar código abaixo após o *loop* da sua aplicação servidor (alterando o valor `".div"` pela classe dos elementos em questão):

```
<script>
$(".div").each(function(){
   $(this).outerHeight(true) < 200 ? $(this).css('height','200px') : 0;
});
</script>
```

Comment: Mas eu tive que correr para o css que estava melhor... sei que não tem haver com a pergunta, mas o css me deu opção de jogar tanto valor minimo, quanto o valor máximo. No query também conseguiria, mas o CSS é mais leve para este caso.
Obrigado!